# Define dependencies between workflows in Argo Workflows

Tags: argo-workflows, argoproj

I am trying to schedule a workflow `C` when both workflows `A` and `B` complete their daily run.

Is there any way to do this without using the [workflow of workflows](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/workflow-of-workflows/) pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `A` and `B` run in parallel.

If you could incorporate workflows `A` and `B` into a single workflow `AB` with parallel steps `A` and `B`, then you could use a [mutex](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/synchronization-mutex-wf-level.yaml) to delay the execution of `C` until after `AB` finishes.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow
metadata:
  name: AB
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  workflowSpec:
    entrypoint: AB
    synchronization:
      mutex:
        name: AB-C-mutex
    templates:
      - name: AB
        steps:
          - - name: A
              templateRef:
                name: A
                template: A
            - name: B
              templateRef:
                name: B
                template: B
---
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: CronWorkflow
metadata:
  name: C
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  workflowSpec:
    entrypoint: C
    synchronization:
      mutex:
        name: AB-C-mutex   
 templates:
# The rest of the workflow.
```

You would need to make sure `C` starts long enough after `AB` for `AB` to claim the mutex.

You could avoid combining `A` and `B` into one workflow if Argo supported using more than one mutex/semaphore per workflow. Currently, there are [no plans to support that](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/2550#issuecomment-773475188).

Another option would be to combine all three workflows into a single workflow (with `A` and `B` running in parallel before `C`).

Comment: Probably what would have helped is exactly the possibility to support multiple semaphores, as of now I understand there's no way of doing it in a fully "decoupled" way and "grouping" workflows is the best solution so far.

Comment: @Vektor88 they'd probably consider it if you opened a feature request, especially since other folks have expressed interest.